# jQuery UI Datepicker - cannot change date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI - v1.12.1 datepicker for an input field created dynamically, the datepicker is working but I cannot change the date format.

This is how I'm initializing the picker

```
$('body').on('focus',"#datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code ! It might help you!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('focus', "#datepicker", function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
});
```

Comment: I had used that before as i need the datepicker for dynamically created input field that solution will not work.

Comment: Can you make a JsFiddle ?